# Keep form result in memory

Tags: python, flask, state, wtforms

[image: Form mock-up]

The image above gives an example of what I hope to achieve with flask.
For now I have a list of tuples such as `[(B,Q), (A,B,C), (T,R,E,P), (M,N)]`.
The list can be any length as well as the tuples. When I `submit` or `pass` my form, I receive the data one the server side, all good.

However now I am asked to remember the state of previously submited ad passed forms in order to go back to it and eventually modify the information.

What would be the best way to remember the state of the forms?

- Python dictionary with the key being the form number as displayed at the bottom (1 to 4)
- Store the result in an SQL table and query it every time I need to access a form again
- Other ideas?

**Notes:** The raw data should be kept for max one day, however, the data are to be processed to generate meaningful information to be stored permanently. Hence, if a modification is made to the form, the final database should reflect it.

Comment: Well it depends on whether you want the storage to be persistent... Say someone submits it. Do you want to be able to retrieve that a month later?

Comment: No it would be only for a day, The real result is processed to get a meaningful information that is then stored permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will very much depend on how the application is built.

One option is to simply always return all the answers posted, with each request, but that won't work well if you have a lot of data.

Although you say that you need the data to be accessible for a day. So it seems reasonable to store it to a database. Performing select queries using the indexed key is rather insignificant for most cases.

Comment: My approach will be to have a temporary database that will store the result for a day, and then at a specific time process the data stored there to the permanent database. This way, people can modify within the day the form answers as many time as they want and only during the night does it write the true processed values into the real database. For each query I will only return the form information and not the whole table for scaling purposes. Their will be a column with the form number in the table to retrieve it easily.

Comment: That sounds like an unnecessary complexity... You can simply store the creation date of your form data, and on your queries only allow data within 24 hours to be retrieved.

Comment: I am just going to store the information temporarily since I don't need it in the long run. I am currently looking at serialization as a good alternative. I'll let you know.